# How do you upload an image from a device to a backend server?

Tags: android, react-native

I am using React Native version `0.35.0` and haven't found a good way to upload an image from device to a backend server. I can easily grab the URI to the image asset on device:

[image]

And I want to send a POST to a remote server so I can save it in DB (or S3).

```
const data = new FormData()
data.append('image', image)
// TODO: send this to server
```

However, I only have access to the `uri` of the image. How do I grab the actual file to attach to a `FormData` and send it to server?

Here's a related GH Issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/201

Comment: Volley is great library. I used it before and I don't recall any issues. There are a lot of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using any library to pick the image from gallery? You can get the data in base64 format and send it to server.

Try this library: https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker

If this wont work for you, paste the code you are using for getting urls and I will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use react-native-fs library to read files and other file-folder processes.

https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs

**readFile(filepath: string, encoding?: string): Promise**

> Reads the file at path and return contents. encoding can be one of
>   utf8 (default), ascii, base64. Use base64 for reading binary files.